# Add values from two textboxes and display the sum in third textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have tried this code to add from textbox1.text and textbox2.text into textbox3.text

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))

         { 
             textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text).ToString());
         }
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))

        {
        textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text).ToString());
        }
    }
```

please Help ... and is there anything like to change 'format 'property of textbox to general number?

Comment: Could you specify the problem?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, then please use the `homework` tag.

Comment: Zortkuns answer will do the trick but you don´t need two eventhandlers for this. They are equal. Bind one handler to both texboxes instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You made a mistake `||` should be replace with `&&` so it will check both the text boxes are filled with value.

You have used `.ToString()` method wrongly which applies only to `textbox2`, check the brackets properly.

```
textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text).ToString());
```

should be

```
textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
```

Try This Tested Code.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
  textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
 }
    
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
  textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
 }
```

Comment: i entered 25 in textbox1 and when i entered  25 in textbox2 .. textbox3 displayed '2525'

Answer (score 5):

Your current expression is missing the negation (!) in the second
   part of your condition

Also, it should be a `&&` not `||`

As for your error, *string was not in the correct format*, you will
   get this with any unsafe code whenever the input string cannot be
   converted to an *int*. Surround it with a `try catch` or use
   `Int32.TryParse`:

```
private void **textBox_TextChanged**(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int first = 0;
     int second= 0;
     if(Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out second) && Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out first))
         textBox3.Text = (first + second ).ToString();
     }
}
```

Btw, like Glenn has pointed out, you can use only one event handler like in this example.

Comment: Shouldn't that be !string.IsNullOrEmpty() `&&` !string.IsNullOrEmpty() ?

Comment: sorry zortkun for misguiding u but i have written d code proper in my program here ive done a mistake . ive tried but having the above error

Comment: yeah this worked ... but instead

textbox3.Text = (first + second).ToString();


i tried 

textbox3.Text =Convert.ToString(first + second); \\ worked too

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))

         { 

             textBox3.Text =convert.toString(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).toString();
         }
```

Comment: ive also tried this riwan . but it is showing me error

'Input string was not in a correct format'

Comment: Where you are getting this error? i have tried it myself and it works and this code which i'm using  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
        {
            TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)).ToString();
        }

Comment: @HMcompfreak just replace your condition  with TextBox1.Text!="" && TextBox2.Text!="" and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)));
        }
    }
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: As per comments from @Glenn - no need to use two event handlers - also - could you comment what you've changed from the original code?

Comment: instead of if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)) change to if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))

Comment: instead of if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)) change to if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)) . For Glenn comment its true you can use single event. Select the text box, go to properties tab then events. Go to TextChanged event and assign select same event.