# OR statement crashing the program but an AND statement works in C#

Tags: c#, string

just starting having a go at building a very simple cashing up program in C# for windows forms and found a very useful answer on adding 2 textboxes together without a button here [Add values from two textboxes and display the sum in third textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394909/add-values-from-two-textboxes-and-display-the-sum-in-third-textbox)

Using this as a basis, I found a solution that worked, but it uses an AND statement to add variables to a string which requires all the inputs to have an entry, which is very practical for what i want to achieve, so, I changed it to use an OR statement as I didn't need every text box to be filled to get an answer.

But when I run it, it crashes, I am pretty sure it is something simple but I am new to C# and am not sure why it is doing this, if the community could point me in the right direction that would be ace!

my code is;

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Business_Done
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void till1Receipts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till1Accounts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till1WorldPay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till1Amex_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till150Pound_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till120Pound_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till110Pound_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till15pound_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till11Pound_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till150p_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till120P_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till110P_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till15P_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till1Copper_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till1Float_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Receipts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Accounts.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1WorldPay.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Amex.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till11Pound.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till150p.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till120P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till110P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till15P.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Copper.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Float.Text))
                    till1Revenue.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Receipts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Accounts.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1WorldPay.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Amex.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till11Pound.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till150p.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till120P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till110P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till15P.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(till1Copper.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1Float.Text)).ToString();

            }

            private void till1XRead_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1Revenue.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(till1XRead.Text))
                    till1Var.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(till1Revenue.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(till1XRead.Text)).ToString();
            }
}
}
```

I have only included the first block, as the other 4 are the same, and didn't want to repeat too much!

thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error message you get? What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: 1. `a && b` isn't a statement, it's an expression. If I talk about fixing your cat when I mean your car, there will be confusion. Words matter. 2.  Convert.ToDecimal() throws an exception when you pass it an empty string. Look at your logic. You were previously only passing non empty strings; now you still do the arithmetic even when one or the other string is empty. You need to write a method that takes two strings, checks each one for empty, and does appropriate conversion and arithmetic.

Comment: @EdPlunkett `Convert.ToDecimal(null)` actually returns `default(decimal)`. I wasn't expecting this, either.

Comment: @JonathonChase Thank you, I've corrected the comment. Won't help OP though, since a textbox will have empty string instead of null, and that will throw (I just checked!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: If you do the math only when *all* of the inputs are non-null/non-empty, as with your original `&&` logic, then you're guaranteeing that all of those strings can be parsed as decimals.

However, as it is now with `||`, if one of them is an empty string, it still adds all of them, including the empty one. When you try to parse the empty one, that will throw an exception. What you need to do is check each one, and only add the ones that aren't empty. That's a staggeringly complex thing to code by the methods you're using now, but I'll show you a way that makes it very simple and clear.

Second: All but one of those event handlers are identical. You can assign the same handler to multiple events. Just write it once, and assign it to all of the TextChanged events. Here's a much cleaner, simpler way to write it as well:

```
public static decimal AddDecimalStrings(params string[] decimals)
{
    decimal result = 0;

    foreach (var str in decimals)
    {
        result += SafeParseDecimal(str);
    }

    return result;
}

public static decimal SafeParseDecimal(string str)
{
    decimal result = 0;
    Decimal.TryParse(str, out result);
    return result;
}

private void decimalInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = AddDecimalStrings(
                    till1Receipts.Text,
                    till1Accounts.Text,
                    till1WorldPay.Text,
                    till1Amex.Text,
                    till150Pound.Text,
                    till120Pound.Text,
                    till110Pound.Text,
                    till15pound.Text,
                    till11Pound.Text,
                    till150p.Text,
                    till120P.Text,
                    till110P.Text,
                    till15P.Text,
                    till1Copper.Text,
                    till1Float.Text);

    till1Revenue.Text = result.ToString();
}

private void till1XRead_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = SafeParseDecimal(till1Revenue.Text) - SafeParseDecimal(till1XRead.Text);
    till1Var.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

If you add another textbox, this will make it much, much easier to update your code.

Answer (score 0):

The logical AND operator (`&&`) works as follows:
When running `condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && ...`, the program will try to evaluate each of the conditions by their order. If any of them evaluates to `false` it will stop, and will not try to evaluate the rest - since it means the whole `if` statement is `false`. Otherwise, they all evaluate to `true`, which means the whole `if` statement is `true`.

However, the logical OR operator (`||`) works as follows:
When running `condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || ...`, the program will try to evaluate each of the conditions by their order. If any of them evaluates to `true` it will stop, and will not try to evaluate the rest - since it means the whole `if` statement is `true`. Otherwise, they all evaluate to `false`, which means the whole `if` statement is `false`.

With these definitions in mind, pay attention to which condition crashes your program. Run the code in Debug mode and I guess you will get a NullReferenceException on one of the `TextBox` variables.